# Clearing the screen causes a flicker due to no frame back buffer

Tags: c, graphics, drawing

Hey guys I am programming for a primitive type board using some assembly and C, consider the board to be aKin to the old school black and white gameboy.

I am running into a problem while writing a game in that there is no backbuffer. when I clear the screen it draws directly to the screen so that the screen truly is cleared, and thus makes anything I draw invisible, because it is immediately cleared in the next pass. So instead of replacing a drawn screen with a new drawn screen, it clears the screen then draws it.

I came up with a hackish solution in where I Limited the rendering to 10 frames per second.
The way I do this is by clearing the screen, drawing the shape, and then burning a loop for however long remains in the 1/10th second. This way whatever is drawn will stay there longer, and be visible longer, allowing the user to see it before it is immediately erased.
i.e.

```
while (1)
{
    doRender = 1;
    screen_clear();
    draw_circle(x,y,20,1);
    while(doRender)
    {
                // a interrupt will set doRender to 0, thus ending the loop
    }
}
```

This works!! sort of, it creates a flicker, not horrible, but noticeable to be sure. My game does not require incredible framerates, 10/sec will do.

Does anyone have a better solution to my issue?

Comment: instead of clearing, can you draw over existing screen with "black" only on the stuff that needs to be cleared ... like draw_circle(x,y,20,0); ???

Comment: Are you on Windows or a unixoid system?

Comment: @FUZxxl: from the description (akin to the gameboy), I assume bare metal.

Comment: Yup, bare metal, were talking a 16bit chip running at a max 16Mhz. Fun stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is good. Try optimize it by clearing only the area where the circle has been drawn.

Comment: I thought about this. When It is time to move any object, I will first have to clear the object at its current location, then change its x,y values, and then redraw it. Seems like a bit of extra work, but you gotta do what you gotta do right? Thanks, ill look into this more and give it a go.

Comment: Much better, flicker is barely noticeable now.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use XOR rendering. E.g: you XOR your sprite to the screen to render it, then on the next frame XOR it again at the same place to remove it and XOR it in its new place.

Can you wait for the vsync? If your drawing is fast enough, you may be able to do it during the vertical blank interval, removing any remaining flicker.

Comment: This is an excellent idea, I may use it elsewhere though. I decided to try writing my own backBuffer, and am 1/2 way done. May use this to write to the buffer.

Comment: @WIllJBD: There is also AND-OR rendering, useful for when you have a non-solid-black background: AND a sprite mask to the background, then OR the sprite.